# Sequelize.js how to show error on create when using the .on("error") syntax?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out how to pass the reason for a failed creation to the client.

I am using the suggested Status code and I want to add the description in the X-Status-Reason header. But when using the .on('') syntax I dont know how to pass the err object to the callback function

Thank you

```
    player.create({
      name:  req.body.name,
      fname: req.body.fname,
      email: req.body.email,
    })
    .on('success', function(player1) {
      res.status(201).jsonp(player1);
      console.log('Player creation worked!')
    })
    .on('error', function(player1) {
      res.header("X-Status-Reason:", "where is my err.description?");
      res.status(400).jsonp( player1);
      console.log('An error in player creation')
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument passed to the error callback with be `err`, not `player1`